# Solution Explorer shows error in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Instead of seeing solution explorer in the latest Visual Studio version (16.10.1) I see this error message:

```
An error occurred while initializing the frame's content
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: format
   at Microsoft.Requires.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.FrameMoniker.ToString(String format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.LogContentCreationException(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.HandleContentCreationException(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.EnsureContentConstructed()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.PreloadOnScreenContent(View view)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.set_FrameView(View value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowManagerService.CreateContentPane(FrameMoniker frameMoniker, Boolean isDocument, String lpstrMkDoc, UInt32 eCreateWindowFlags, Object punkView, Object punkData, IServiceProvider pServiceProvider, IVsUIHierarchy pUIHierarchy, UInt32 vsid, Guid rguidCmdUI, ViewGroup parent, IVsWindowFrame& ppWindowFrame)
```

Don't know how to get rid of it, have been working around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting all settings resolved the problem:

https://www.technipages.com/visual-studio-reset-all-settings